# Get Value From Dynamically Populated Hidden Field

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc-4

Hi I am new to MVC and I have hidden fields that are populated through jQuery on a checkbox change event.

Is it possible to then get this value and use it in an MVC `@Html.ActionLink`?

Sample code:

```
<div class="col-md-3" style="text-align: center;">
    <label style="text-decoration: underline;">Quote 3</label>
    <br />
    <label id="lblQuote3"></label>
    <input type="hidden" id="hdfQuote3" />
</div>

<div class="col-md-3 compareButtonDiv" style="text-align: center;">
    @Html.ActionLinkNonEncoded("Compare Risks", "CompareRisks", "Lead", routeValues: new { bid = @Request.QueryString.Get("bid") }, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "btn btn-primary btn-md", @title = "Compare Risks" }) 
</div>
```

I am trying to get the value from the hidden field `lblQuote3` and send that value to the controller.  I think to send the value I include it in the `rootValues`.

Comment: You need to use javascipt/jquery to modify the `href` attribute of your link

Comment: @StephenMuecke something like this? `$("a").attr("href", "http://www.google.com/")`

Comment: Yes, that would work (but is the hidden input really necessary - the function that updates the inputs could just update the href attribute?)

Comment: Yeah, I still need the hidden field.  Your answer has worked for me! Thanks :)

Comment: if you want to make it an answer I can mark it so

Comment: Happy for you to post you own answer with the actual code you used, but I just posted [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30731582/pass-a-javascript-variable-as-parameter-to-url-action/30733494#30733494) to a similar issue which you might be interested in

Answer (score 0):

After taking advice from [Stephen Muecke](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3559349/stephen-muecke) I was able to build a solution to my problem.

On my page, I have dynamically added checkboxes that when their checked property changes a function is called to either add or remove text to/from a `<label>`.

This text was then to be added to, or removed from, the `href` of a `button`.

The solution I came up with was to write a couple of functions that handle all the logic I require.

**Checkbox On Change event:**

```
$('input[type="checkbox"].style2').checkbox().on('change', function () {
        var compareRiskLinkObject = $('#lnkCompareRisks');
        var compareRiskLinkHref = compareRiskLinkObject.attr('href');
        var QuoteRef = "";
        var checkboxID = $(this).attr('id');
        QuoteRef = $(this).siblings('#hdfQuoteRef').val();

        if ($(this).prop('checked')) {
            checkAndStoreToAvailableRiskSlot(QuoteRef, checkboxID, compareRiskLinkObject, compareRiskLinkHref);
        } else {
            checkAndRemoveFromRiskSlot(QuoteRef, compareRiskLinkObject, compareRiskLinkHref);
        }
    });
```

**Functions called:**

```
function checkAndStoreToAvailableRiskSlot(quoteRef, checkboxID, linkbutton, href) {
    // get IDs of 3 risk slots
    var risk1 = $('#lblQuote1');
    var risk2 = $('#lblQuote2');
    var risk3 = $('#lblQuote3');
    var hdf1 = $('#hdfQuote1');
    var hdf2 = $('#hdfQuote2');
    var hdf3 = $('#hdfQuote3');

    if (risk1.text() == "") {
        risk1.text(quoteRef);
        hdf1.val(checkboxID);
        appendHrefWithRisks(linkbutton, href, "risk1=" + quoteRef);
    } else if (risk1.text() != "" && risk2.text() == "") {
        risk2.text(quoteRef);
        hdf2.val(checkboxID);
        appendHrefWithRisks(linkbutton, href, "risk2=" + quoteRef);
    } else if (risk1.text() != "" && risk2.text() != "" && risk3.text() == "") {
        risk3.text(quoteRef);
        hdf3.val(checkboxID);
        appendHrefWithRisks(linkbutton, href, "risk3=" + quoteRef);
    } else {
        alert("You have already selected 3 quotes.  Please uncheck one before adding another.");
    }
}



function checkAndRemoveFromRiskSlot(quoteRef, linkbutton, href) {
    // get IDs of 3 risk slots
    var risk1 = $('#lblQuote1');
    var risk2 = $('#lblQuote2');
    var risk3 = $('#lblQuote3');

    if (risk1.text() === quoteRef) {
        risk1.text("");
        removeFromHref(linkbutton, "risk1", href);
    } else if (risk1.text() !== quoteRef && risk2.text() === quoteRef) {
        risk2.text("");
        removeFromHref(linkbutton, "risk2", href);
    } else if (risk1.text() !== quoteRef && risk2.text() !== quoteRef && risk3.text() === quoteRef) {
        risk3.text("");
        removeFromHref(linkbutton, "risk3", href);
    } else {
        alert("You have already selected 3 quotes.  Please uncheck one before adding another.");
    }
}

function appendHrefWithRisks(linkbutton, href, appendData) {
    var newHref = "";
    newHref = href + '&' + appendData;
    linkbutton.attr('href', newHref);
}

function removeFromHref(linkbutton, risk, href) {
    var newHref = "";

    if (risk == "risk1") {
        newHref = href.replace(/&?((risk1))=[^&]*/gi, "");
    } else if (risk == "risk2") {
        newHref = href.replace(/&?((risk2))=[^&]*/gi, "");
    } else if (risk == "risk3") {
        newHref = href.replace(/&?((risk3))=[^&]*/gi, "");
    }
    linkbutton.attr('href', newHref);
}
```

When a checked box is checked it call on, `function checkAndStoreToAvailableRiskSlot` which in turn calls the `function appendHrefWithRisks`.

The `href` of the link button is passed through the methods and then appended on the successful addition of a risk to a label.

Hopefully this helps someone else someday :)